# dynamic link - navigate to app if it is installed or navigate to app store or play store if it is not installed (react-native)

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

After testing on real device I want to navigate dynamic link to app or app/play store directly without having bridge of browser, currently dynamic link is working fine but it is navigating to browser first and then to app if it is installed else navigates to browser first and then play store or app store.
I need to do direct navigation without going to browser first.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JioTL.png)
Steps which I followed.

1. Created dynamic link using Firebase.
2. Added behaviour of ios and android for both the scenario and linked app respectively.
   3.Added team id, app store id to project setting in firebase and apple-app-site-association file is up on domain which created by dynamic link.
   4.Added Android intent filter in androidMainfest.xml

   ```html
       <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                           <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                           <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.example.com"/
   </intent-filter>
   ```
3. Associated bundle id, domain to xcode for ios.
4. Installed package for dynamic link in project.
   yarn add @react-native-firebase/dynamic-links
   cd ios/ && pod install[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVpV7.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to campaign tracking, social tags and advanced options inside dynamic link tab, and check the check box  skip the app preview page (not recommended). It works for me